# How to make a custom combo box in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, box

I have been struggling to find a way to provide custom background colour to the combo box control in WPF.
The background property doesn't seem to change the combo box colour.
What should be done to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the default control template of the `ComboBox`. Please refer to the following link for more information about how to do this.

**Changing the background colour of a ComboBox in WPF on Windows 8:** https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/04/30/changing-the-background-colour-of-a-combobox-in-wpf-on-windows-8/